# Disable or gray a previous days in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to gray or disable the previous days for the purpose of user can not select them, I tried `minDate= 0` or `new date()` but it does not work, so I did it manually but I still have the piece of code to gray them.

Datepicker:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
```

Code to display an alert when the date of the datepicker is less than today on change

```
 //Disable pastdays

 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd;}
 if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm;}
 var today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
   jQuery( "#datepicker .form-control" ).change(function() {
      if (jQuery("#datepicker .form-control").val() < today) {
              alert('You can not select a date lower than today!')
      }
   });
 //end Disable pastDay
```

Comment: which of the 4 billion datepickers are you using? They *all* have a way to disable specific dates

Comment: is it good to compare dates with `<` sign?

Comment: i dont know i used this one : http://codepen.io/Yuping/pen/xqrjE @Jamiec

Comment: Ok, well `startDate` works exactly as expected as described in the [docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#id6). eg: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpJYBa what's your problem?

Comment: it works with startDate, before i used minDate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put **startDate: new Date()**   inside your datepicker configuration object

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
      autoclose: true, 
      todayHighlight: true,
      startDate: new Date()
 });
```

Comment: it works thanks @Atanu Mallick just i want to know if it is possible to put some color in this days that are disabled ?

Comment: @user7616808 you'll notice that it adds a class `.disabled` to all table cells with a disabled day. You can just use css to style those

Answer (score -1):

Used  below code to disabled datepicker

```
jQuery("#datepicker .form-control").change(function (e) {
            if (jQuery("#datepicker .form-control").val() < today) {
                alert('You can not select a date lower than today!');
                jQuery(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This works in the provided codepen as per the docs.

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-end-date="0d">
```

**data-date-end-date="0d"** will disable all dates after today.